# Trying to identify a novel with dragons

Tags: story-identification, novel, dragons

Back in elementary school, about in 1999, I read a fantasy novel, I think it was called "land of gold" or something but I may be completely off in this.

The plot was about a group people and a dragon. The people were looking for other dragons because they were concerned the dragon with them might be the last of its (her? not sure) kind. They followed up several leads and encountered a number of non dragon but draconic creatures.

In the end they do find another dragon and everything is resolved happily. The dragon with them is intelligent and can talk.

The novel is a stand alone and not part of any series. If anyone knows the book I'm talking about I'd be very grateful. I believe the novel was a young adult novel but I am uncertain.

Comment: How long ago was elementary school for you?

Comment: sorry, 14 years ago, about 1999

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're referring to "[The Land of Gold](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/gillian-bradshaw/the-land-of-gold/)" by Gillian Bradshaw;

[image]

There's a description [here](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/gillian-bradshaw/the-land-of-gold/);

> In a sequel to The Dragon and the Thief (1991), the benign and
>   articulate dragon Hathor and her klutzy but quick-witted Egyptian
>   friend Prahotep join forces with an indomitable Nubian princess.
>   Kandaki wakes to the sounds of her parents' murder; she escapes
>   because the usurper hopes to marry her. Foiled by her intransigence,
>   he dispatches her to be fed to a water dragon; fortunately, our dragon
>   and friends intervene, and are soon involved in reclaiming Kandaki's
>   rightful place on the Nubian throne. With sieges, attacks, and a march
>   across a monster-infested desert, there's plenty of action; even more
>   fun are the ways Prahotep and Kandaki outwit their
>   enemies--unobtrusively but effectively, Bradshaw makes the point that
>   many different talents are valuable, especially in concert. In the
>   end, Prahotep's characteristic (but unwarranted) modesty almost
>   prevents the obvious happy union, while the dragon also finds the mate
>   she's long been seeking. As funny, lively, and altogether delightful
>   as its predecessor

Comment: Yes! I'm almost completely certain you're right. Thanks